# what is Sakkayaditti whats it meaning

Tags: early-buddhism

I have read about sakkayaditti

https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/sakkayaditti

Sakkayaditti means something in Buddhism, Pali.
please help me to clarify

Answer (score 3):

This is a key concept in the Early Buddhist Texts:

> [MN 64](https://suttacentral.net/mn64/en/sujato#mn64:3.4): Anusetvevassa sakkāyadiṭṭhānusayo.
>
> [MN 64](https://suttacentral.net/mn64/en/sujato#mn64:3.4): Yet the underlying tendency to ***identity view*** still lies within them.

Identity View is the view that "I am". For example, we say, "I am Chinese" or "I am educated" or "I am poor", etc.

These personal perspectives contribute to suffering. If "I am poor", then "I want to be rich". If "I am ugly" then "I want to be beautiful". Through study and practice, we step away from personal perspectives and abandon Identity View as not satisfying, not conducive to happiness. To be an Arahant, to be a Realized One, Identity View is abandoned entirely.

Sakkāyadiṭṭhi is the [heresy of individuality](https://suttacentral.net/define/sakk%C4%81yadi%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADhi)

To be clear, that does not mean that Buddhists are all alike. The Buddha in fact insisted that each of us find the truth for ourselves. What it means is that Buddhists are alike in dismissing personal cravings as unskillful and unwholesome.

Comment: why must you idiosyncratically write mn64 rather than conform with what is standard? is this some type of creating a unique self?

Comment: Please explain what is standard? Each link goes to a specific segment. The text is found and generated automatically, so we can conform to any desired standard. What do you suggest?  Oh WAIT. I see that you capped them. Sorry, missed that. The suttasegment id's are all lower case. I'll change the program to add in proper caps. It was a matter of unaware laziness. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Fixed in scv-bilara v1.1.6 https://github.com/sc-voice/scv-bilara/tree/v1.1.6
Thanks for catching this!

Comment: To cap, or not to cap, that is the question. Whether 'tis nobler in mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous spelling, or take arms against a sea of grammar, and by opposing, edit them...

Answer (score 0):

This is misunderstood by many people today. They say sakkaya ditti means: self view. According to dhamma, when a peraon become 1st entrant (sotāpanna) he uproots the sakkaya ditti. So if sakkaya ditti means self view, then that person no need to go beyond that point, since there's noone (no self view) to attain nibbana.
So please think wise and don't get to the trap of self view.

Sakkaya diiti means: giving values to the things (in mind). Eg: Ferrari is a very good car, so its valuable (in mind). The food in ABC restaurant is very tasty so its worth going to that restaurant or eating that food. This view is called sakkaya ditti. When someone become 1st entrant; he understand that its a lie. Its not true. So he uproots the sakkaya dittia and become to samma ditti. Which is knowing that nothing is valuable but the Nirvana.
How to understand / realize that things doesn't have a value is a different topic.

Comment: I voted this answer down because it has no references to support it.

Answer (score 0):

> Ime kho, āvuso visākha, pañcupādānakkhandhā **sakkāyo** vutto
> bhagavatā
>
> These five clinging-aggregates are the **self-identification**
> described by the Blessed One.
>
> The craving that makes for further becoming — accompanied by passion &
> delight, relishing now here & now there — i.e., craving for sensual
> pleasure, craving for becoming, craving for non-becoming: This, friend
> Visakha, is the origination of self-identification described by the
> Blessed One
>
> Kathaṃ panāyye, **sakkāyadiṭṭhi** hotī ti?
>
> But, lady, how does **self-identification view** come about?
>
> There is the case, friend Visakha, where an uninstructed,
> run-of-the-mill person — who has no regard for noble ones, is not
> well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma; who has no regard for men
> of integrity, is not well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma —
> assumes form (the body) to be the self, or the self as possessing
> form, or form as in the self, or the self as in form.
>
> He assumes feeling to be the self...
>
> He assumes perception to be the self...
>
> He assumes (mental) fabrications to be the self...
>
> He assumes consciousness to be the self, or the self as possessing
> consciousness, or consciousness as in the self, or the self as in
> consciousness.
>
> This is how self-identification view comes about.
>
> [MN 44](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.044.than.html)